# What does “to quorble a stank at” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, books

In the foreword to *The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy* by Douglas Adams, the following sentence occurs:

> You will find quantum tomfoolery, cosmic belly laughs and more absurd one-liners than you could **quorble a stank at**.

I haven’t the slightest notion of what *quorble* and *stank at* mean there. Browsing through dictionaries hasn't helped.

Comment: This is deliberate nonsense, a nod to the Douglas Adams's own "hoopy frood".

Comment: It's Douglas Adam's unique way of saying. Than **you can shake a stick at!** http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/more_than_one_can_shake_a_stick_at

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about "English"

Comment: @Fumble: Perhaps that's true in hindsight, but there's no way to know that at the time of asking. Moreover, there was a time when the word "jabberwocky" wouldn't have been a question about English, either, but now that word is in the dictionary. Sometimes the boundaries of English can shift over time.

Comment: So if _quorble_ is a loan-word in English, does it need italics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the HHG2G, which is known for being silly and nonsensical at times. They don’t mean anything except in so far as they are [literary nonsense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_nonsense). In this case I would say they are meant as a nonsensical parallel construction to “shake a stick at”.